# Difference in rendering from Matlab2tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, matlab2tikz

I have a 3D object produced from Matlab which is like this:
[image]

I would like use a vector graphics of the above in my document. However due to the file size, I prefer to save as tikz picture. I used Matlab2tikz for the above picture and got the following one:

[image]

I have no concerns about the labels, but can someone help me get the same rendering or a near similar one?

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: @samcarter Do you mean the tikz code?

Comment: Yes, the tikz code. Probably nobody wants to spent ages to recreate it just to change the colours.

Comment: Here: https://pastebin.com/aRvFTvbe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot post the full code due to length constrictions, but this is what I did:

- removed the first `\addplot3`
- removed the `fill=white!85!black` to see the already existing shading
- Use a suitable colour scale for the desired shading

---

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{grffile}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=4.895in,
height=5.264in,
at={(4.102in,0.71in)},
scale only axis,
plot box ratio=4 1 1,
xmin=-0.5,
xmax=0.5,
tick align=outside,
ymin=-0.125,
ymax=0.125,
zmin=-0.125,
zmax=0.125,
view={-133.1}{69.2},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
axis z line*=left
]

\addplot3[%
surf, z buffer=sort, colormap={my}{
    rgb255=(20,20,20) 
    rgb255=(50,50,50) 
    rgb255=(250,250,250)
}, mesh/rows=21]
table[row sep=crcr, point meta=\thisrow{c}] {%
%
x   y   z   c\\
-0.5    0   0   0\\
-0.498461042574392  0   0.0195543081300289  0.0195543081300289\\
-0.493882064536894  0   0.0386271242968684  0.0386271242968684\\
...
```

[image]

Comment: That's a strong progress! Can we do something more about the lighting too?

Comment: @SathishKrishnan You can change it by selecting a suitable colour palette.

Comment: @SathishKrishnan You're welcome!

Comment: Also, please update the code in the pastebin for future users.

Comment: @SathishKrishnan Ups, I forgot about pastebin. Don't have the code any more.